# Change ListBox style without going to the top

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ObservableCollection binded to the source of a ListBox. The ListBox uses a Style to display a button at the end of the ListBox to "Load more" content. When the last content is loaded, I change the Style of the ListBox, so that it displays "No more posts".

The problem is that the ListBox goes to the top (first item) when changing the Style.. Any way to prevent this?

```
// iterate over items
foreach (Record rec in root.data.records)
{
    // add items to observablecollection
}

// check if there are more items
if (root.data.nextPage == 0)
{
    // there are no more items => set style with "no more posts"
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => listbox.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["listboxend"]);
    return;
}
else
{
    // there are still more items => set style with button
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => listbox.Style = (Style)this.Resources["listboxwithbutton"]);
}
```

Strange thing: in the beginning the listbox has no style. When I set the "listboxwithbutton" style, the listbox doens't go to the top... Only when setting "listboxend" style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListBox.ScrollIntoView(listBoxItem)` to scroll to the listBoxItem whenever you are changing the Style. Assuming that now you know how to obtain this. Good luck.

Comment: I can't use this because I change the style when I go in the "Load more" function and see that the next items being added at that time are the last ones. So the user hasn't scrolled to the bottom when I change the style. I hope you understand.